# Создание горячих клавиш в delphi

Tags: delphi

Как с помощью `delphi` делать в программах горячие клавиши? Пожалуйста, если можно, подробно.

Answer (score 2):

Регестрируем обработчик

```
 Application.OnMessage := AppMessage;
```

Сам обработчик

```
procedure TfmMain.AppMessage(var Msg: TMsg; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
if (Msg.message = WM_KEYDOWN)   and (Msg.wParam = VK_F1) then
SendHelpMessage(Handle);
end;
```

Вот собственно и все

Answer (score 0):

Еще
если используется **mainMenu** или **PopUpMenu** то можно сразу на действие присваивать горячие клавиши.
В инспекторе свойство **ShortCut** по умолчанию стоит **none**